# Specify type of collection in UML Diagram Class

Tags: class, collections, uml, diagram

I have a problem what I want to represent using a UML class diagram.
I have a class A that has its own name and a collection (0 .. *) of elements of B.
The class B, however, is abstract and therefore the collection of elements in A can be B1 or B2 (specializations of B).
I would like to clarify the fact that the collection has to present in its entirety to all of B1 or B2, that does not allow to mix different elements, but I have no idea how to represent this on UML. Your advice would definitely help.

```
+---+
| A |
+---+
  |
  |0..*
+---+    +----+
| B |<---| B1 |
+---+    +----+
  ^
  |
+----+
| B2 |
+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two real collections based on an abstract one (or and interface). Make reference from A to this abstract collection. As it is abstract, for the realization you HAVE to take one of these instantionable ones. It is one more use of an abstract class.

[image]

I am afraid, I can't manage it in so nice old-fashioned alphanumerical graphics.

Also, I think, it would be better to add an explaining note anyway. For it could be hard to understand.

Edit: I want to appraise your wish to realize the concept on the class level, not if-then-else one. This way we can really GUARANTEE there will be no mixing types in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Collections in UML are defined implicitly. If attribute or association end has multiplicity set to more than one, it is collection. Element types in the collection are types assigned to attribute or association ends. Collection types are defined by paraneters isOrdered, isUnique of musltiplicity. it is depicted by keywords close to attribute (association end).